# what do you call the edge that goes along ironed trousers?

Tags: word-request

When you move a heated iron up and down a pair of trousers it causes the trousers to fold and a resulting line is noticeable on the front of the trousers. what do you call that "line"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That line is called a **crease.**

> crease
>   noun
>   a line on cloth or paper where it has been folded or crushed:
>
> He ironed a crease down the front of each trouser leg.

[Crease](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crease)

Answer (score 2):

A ***traveler's crease*** is the specific crease in the front of fancy slacks. As [one  website](https://www.menshealth.com/style/a19532225/when-to-iron-crease-into-pants/) says:

> The crease that runs vertically down the front of most slacks – pants that aren’t chinos or denim – is there to add sharpness and sophistication to your look. This fold, **also known as a traveler’s crease**, helps keep your pants neat when you hang them in a garment bag as well. You’ll typically find them on work, semi-formal, or formal pants.